# diaplay only the latest added field in a database table

Tags: php, mysql, content-management-system

I am creating a new project which is a podcast site.

**on this site I wish to display the title, description and audio file of only the latest added content.**

I have this code for my *index.php*

```
<?php

include_once('include/connection.php');
include_once('include/article.php');

$cast = new cast;
$articles = $cast->fetch_all();

?>

<html>

<head>
<title>Podcast Website</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>
<?php include_once('header.php'); ?>
<body>
<div class="container">

<ol>

<h1>Latest Episode</h1>

    <?php foreach ($articles as $cast) { ?>

<b><?php echo $cast['cast_title']; ?></b>
<br><br>
<audio controls>
  <source src="<?php echo $cast['cast_audio']; ?>" type="audio/mpeg">
  <source src="<?php echo $cast['cast_audio']; ?>" type="audio/ogg">
  Your browser does not support this audio format.
</audio> <br><br>
<?php echo $cast['cast_about']; ?><br><br>
<a href="episode.php?id=<?php echo $cast['cast_id']; ?>">
<font size="2">View show notes</font></a>

<br><br><divider /><br><br>


 <?php } ?>
</ol>
<br><br>
<h2>Past Episodes<h2>
<br><br>
<br><small><a href="admin">admin</small></a>
</div>
</body>
<?php include_once('footer.php'); ?>

</html>
```

this displays both of my listings but I only need it to display the latest.

how can I get it to **only display 1** where it says `<h1>Latest Episode</h1>`.

if you need any more info then please ask and I will provide.

please help.

Thank you.

Kev